# Remove white spaces in string without split function

Tags: python, split

Need to remove all excess white spaces in a string, including ones at the beginning and end. I cannot use the split function. Only if and while statements. I have this so far, but every time i run it, it only returns the input the exact same way.

```
def cleanstring(S):
  i=0
  startpos=0
  endpos=0
  end=-1
  word=0


  #find position of first letter
  while S[i]==(" "):
    i=i+0
    startpos=i

  #find last letter
  while (S[end]==(" ")):
     end=end-1
     endpos=S[len(S)-end]

  #make first letter found the first letter in the string
  if S[i]!=(" "):
    word=S[i]

  #start between startpos and endpos to find word
  while (i<endpos) and (i>startpos):
    while S[i]!=(" "):
      word=word+S[i]
    if S[i]==(" "):
      if (S[i+1]==("")) or (S[i-1]==(" ")):
        word=word+(" ")
      else:
        word=word+(" ")
  #return the word
 print(word)

Input=["   Hello to   the world    "]
```

Comment: `white space` is actually a bit broader than just space (`' '`) but also includes `\t` and `\n` -- are you trying to remove excess white space or just excess space?

Comment: excess white space, so leave spaces in between each word, but not more than one

Comment: The point of my question is what you meant by the term `white space`. Your code is simply looking at spaces, and ignores tabs and newlines (which also count as white space according to the standard definition of that term). Is that by design, or is it a bug in your code?

Comment: what do you mean remove, what should the output be?

Comment: output should be "Hello to the world"

Comment: @ecj then you are stripping whitespace not splitting

Comment: Input.replace('  ', '').strip()

Comment: @ECJ: please update your question. You wrote "remove spaces", but this is not what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Concat as you go to a temp string, if you hit a whitespace char check if the temp string is not empty, if not yield it and reset the temp string.

```
s = "    Hello to   the world    "
def split(s):
    temp_s = ""
    for ch in s:
        if ch.isspace():
            if temp_s:
               yield temp_s
               temp_s = ""
        else:
            temp_s += ch
    if temp_s:
        yield temp_s
```

Output:

```
In [5]: s = "    Hello to   the world    "

In [6]: list(split(s))
Out[6]: ['Hello', 'to', 'the', 'world']

In [7]: s = "    Hello\tto\r\nthe world    "

In [8]: list(split(s))
Out[8]: ['Hello', 'to', 'the', 'world']

In [10]: list(split(s))
Out[10]: ['Hello', 'world']

In [11]: s = "Hello"

In [12]: list(split(s))
Out[12]: ['Hello']
```

Obviously if needed you can change the for's to a while loops.

Answer (score 0):

If you call your cleanstring function with a string with a space in it, this will cause an infinite loop:

```
while S[i]==(" "):
    i=i+0
    startpos=i
```

Since you are adding zero to i, it will never change. You should increment it by 1, which can be done like this:

```
i += 1
```

which is short hand for

```
i = i + 1
```

However, Input is not even a string, but a list with a string in it. You should change the input expression to this

```
Input = "   Hello to   the world    "
```

The square brackets you have are making it a list with a string in it.

Comment: Your function is not going to work even when you do these two things, but it will get you further along. I advice putting print statements to see what your values are to help you trace through the code. It takes a while to get the hang of it, but keep trying and you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `for`:

```
def cleanstring(str_in):
    str_out = ''
    last_char = None
    for cur_char in str_in:
        str_out += '' if last_char == ' ' and cur_char ==' ' else cur_char
        last_char = cur_char
    return str_out
```

Using `while`:

```
def cleanstring(str_in):
    str_out = ''
    last_char = None
    index = 0
    while str_in[index:index+1]:
        cur_char = str_in[index:index+1]
        str_out += '' if last_char == ' ' and cur_char ==' ' else cur_char
        last_char = cur_char
        index+=1
    return str_out
```

If the last character and current are spaces then do not append a space.

We assume that spaces are the only whitespace concerned. Otherwise this is a solution for sets of whitespace:

```
def cleanstring(str_in):
    str_out = ''
    last_char = None
    index = 0
    whitespace = [' ','\t','\n','\r','\f','\v']
    while str_in[index:index+1]:
        a = str_in[index:index+1]
        str_out += '' if last_char in whitespace and a in whitespace else a
        last_char = a
        index+=1
    return str_out
```

That removes all whitespace aside from the first detected entry, however if we want to remove whitespace that is similar to adjacent whitespace and leave the first detected instance:

```
def cleanstring(str_in):
    str_out = ''
    last_char = None
    index = 0
    whitespace = [' ','\t','\n','\r','\f','\v']
    while str_in[index:index+1]:
        a = str_in[index:index+1]
        str_out += '' if last_char == a and a in whitespace else a
        last_char = a
        index+=1
    return str_out
```

If you are concerned about the use of `in`, it can be replaced with (using last instance of `cleanstring` as example):

```
def cleanstring(str_in):
    def is_whitespace_in(char):
        whitespace = [' ','\t','\n','\r','\f','\v']
        local_index = 0
        while whitespace[local_index:local_index+1]:
            a = whitespace[local_index:local_index+1][0]
            if a[0] == char:
                return True
            local_index+=1
        return False

    str_out = ''
    last_char = None
    index = 0
    while str_in[index:index+1]:
        a = str_in[index:index+1]
        str_out += '' if last_char == a and is_whitespace_in(a) else a
        last_char = a
        index+=1
    return str_out
```

Whitespace of the last examples follows from [Cython `re`'s `\s` definition](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/re.py):

> ```
> \s       Matches any whitespace character; equivalent to [ \t\n\r\f\v] in
>          bytes patterns or string patterns with the ASCII flag.
> ```
>
> Lines 73-74

I know this may not be the most Pythonic or PEP8 compliant, please feel free to edit this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `string.strip()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Is this kind of homework or something?
If you can't use 'for', only 'if' and 'while', then I'd use a counter and check for each char in your string.

```
def clean(input):
    idx = 0
    out = input[idx]
    while idx < len(input):
        if input[idx] != out[-1] or input[idx] != ' ':
            out += input[idx]
        idx+=1
    return out
```

Of course, it's not the full solution, but you get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

Please read the comment below.

```
TABLE = str.maketrans('','',' \n\r\t\f')

def clrstr(inp):
    return inp.translate(TABLE)
```

However, it does not help much if you are learning while and for loops.

Comment: This code removes all white space without split, because this is what was asked in the question. The intention was changed to remove only EXCESS white spaces in the comments which I have overlooked.